# Vuetify Slider set value from vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to set an existing value from my vuex store to my vuetify slider. But it always positions to 0.

This is my slider / my code:

```
   <v-slider
     v-model="sizeOfFont"
     :max="40"
     :value="pureFontSize || ''"
     @change="changeFontSize()"
     append-icon="mdi-format-size"
   ></v-slider>

export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
    sizeOfFont: '',
  }),

  computed:  {
    ...mapState(['font', 'fontSize']),

    pureFontSize() {
      return this.fontSize.toString().replace('px', '');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeFontSize() {
      this.$store.commit('setFontSize', `${this.sizeOfFont}px`);
    },
 }
```

If I `console.log` this.fontSize it actually returns the saved fontsize from my vuex store but I am unable to set it as a default value to my slider.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example using JSFiddle or CodePen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using both `v-model`, `value` and `change` event to control the font property, and they are interacting with each other. You should use either `v-model` or a combination of `value` and `change` event to control the property, something like the following with `v-model` only:

```
<v-slider
  v-model="sizeOfFont"
  :max="40"
  append-icon="mdi-format-size"
></v-slider>

export default Vue.extend({
  computed:  {
    ...mapState(['font', 'fontSize']),
    
    sizeOfFont: {
      get() {
        return this.fontSize.toString().replace('px', '');
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$store.commit('setFontSize', `${val}px`);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And then in your Vuex store, you can give `sizeOfFont` a default value, which should be picked up by `v-model`.

Comment: Should I always use it like in your case with a computed getter and setter?

Comment: It depends on your use case, a computed property doesn't need a setter if you don't need to change its value directly. You can also use a combination of `:value` and `@change` to make this happen.

Comment: So basically the set method would act as a change right? Bouth run if a change occurs and in this case saves the current value (val) to the store. Thanks btw :)

Comment: Sure, glad it works for you. And yes, the set method is invoked when `v-slider` tries to change the value of `sizeOfFont` through `v-model`.